# FCM not working on app, the response from Firebase it's alright, notifications does not pop

Tags: android, push-notification

I have tried to implement `FCM` to my app, but somehow the notifications does not pop. I have edited the question because I found out a mistake I've made. Now the `Firebase` connection looks fine, it just seems that the notifications do not want to pop up. I am using the following code to get the response from `Firebase`:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
            sendPushNotification(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

//this method will display the notification
//We are passing the JSONObject that is received from
//firebase cloud messaging
private void sendPushNotification(JSONObject json) {
    //optionally we can display the json into log
    Log.e(TAG, "Notification JSON " + json.toString());
    try {
        //getting the json data
        JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

        //parsing json data
        String title = data.getString("title");
        String message = data.getString("message");
        String imageUrl = data.getString("image");

        //creating MyNotificationManager object
        MyNotificationManager mNotificationManager = new MyNotificationManager(getApplicationContext());

        //creating an intent for the notification


        //if there is no image
        if(imageUrl.equals("null")){
            //displaying small notification
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Harta.class);
            mNotificationManager.showSmallNotification(title, message, intent);
        }else{
            //if there is an image
            //displaying a big notification
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Harta.class);
            mNotificationManager.showBigNotification(title, message, imageUrl, intent);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

}
```

And the NotificationManager class:

```
public class MyNotificationManager {

public static final int ID_BIG_NOTIFICATION = 234;
public static final int ID_SMALL_NOTIFICATION = 235;

private Context mCtx;

public MyNotificationManager(Context mCtx) {
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
}

//the method will show a big notification with an image
//parameters are title for message title, message for message text, url of the big image and an intent that will open
//when you will tap on the notification
public void showBigNotification(String title, String message, String url, Intent intent) {
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    mCtx,
                    ID_BIG_NOTIFICATION,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bigPictureStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
    bigPictureStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
    bigPictureStyle.setSummaryText(Html.fromHtml(message).toString());
    bigPictureStyle.bigPicture(getBitmapFromURL(url));
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mCtx);
    Notification notification;
    notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setStyle(bigPictureStyle)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mCtx.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setContentText(message)
            .build();

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(ID_BIG_NOTIFICATION, notification);
}

//the method will show a small notification
//parameters are title for message title, message for message text and an intent that will open
//when you will tap on the notification
public void showSmallNotification(String title, String message, Intent intent) {
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    mCtx,
                    ID_SMALL_NOTIFICATION,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );


    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mCtx);
    Notification notification;
    notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mCtx.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setContentText(message)
            .build();

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(ID_SMALL_NOTIFICATION, notification);
}

//The method will return Bitmap from an image URL
private Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have run the code multiple ways and checked every step, from the server to the app. Using postman I generated multiple notifications, and the `service` receives the data, in a correct way.
Logcat generated:

```
E/MyFirebaseMsgService: Data Payload: {data={"title":"cityalert","message":"blabla"}}
Notification JSON {"data":{"title":"cityalert","message":"blabla"}}
E/MyFirebaseMsgService: Json Exception: No value for image
```

Considering the log, the app should go and run `sendPushNotification`, which gets the correct `JSONObject data` and the string from the `object`, but then it just stops, without creating the actual notification from the line `mNotificationManager.showSmallNotification(title, message, intent);`, using the method from `MyNotificationManager`.

Comment: did you create a notification channel?

Comment: I managed to solve the issue. I had an error about the image, which was causing my app to run that part. It works properly now, when I send the image too.